# Enabling mathjax on SE sites

Tags: discussion, mathjax

I apologize for hijacking a meta.math thread here, but it was suggested to me that I ask this question on this forum. I'm involved with the theoretical computer science SE site (cstheory.stackexchange.com) and we would also like to enable mathJAX support for our site. 
We're reaching the point where it's difficult to read questions or write answers without effective math rendering (I'm using the John Gietzen greasemonkey script at the client side, but that doesn't work for everyone).

My question is: how did you go about enabling mathJAX support ? I'm asking so that we can follow the same procedure.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that the SO moderators implemented it after math.SE users requested the feature. Cf. this [thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354/feedback-on-google-charts-for-tex-processing). If your site wants it, you should probably start a meta thread for people to voice their opinions, or contact one of the moderators directly.

Comment: we have a meta thread (with 24 votes and counting !). But I don't know how to contact moderators directly.

Comment: @Suresh You can always flag the post for moderator attention. :) But they have probably seen the post.

Comment: @Suresh: Try sending an email to team@stackexchange.com. They are usually pretty good about responding.

Comment: not SO moderators, but rather SE admins, so as others suggested, a meta thread and team@stackexchange.com are good places to start.

Comment: ok will try that as well. thanks for the suggestions.