# Searching and text delimiters

Tags: support, search

On math.meta, when I do a [search for `cstheory`](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=cstheory) I get several results, **none** of which is this one:

[image: unfound question]

(The question is [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/671/enabling-mathjax-on-se-sites).)

For it to find this question as well I have to [search for `cstheory.stackexchange.com`](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=cstheory.stackexchange.com).

The help tips on searching include putting the text in quotes to get "an exact match" which suggests that without
the quotes it matches on any old thing, and should find cstheory in the above.

Why is it unable to find that question?

(I suspect that it isn't found because the cstheory in that question does not have white space delimeters either before or after it, but that's only a guess.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the SE search engine is not able to find that post is because it does not consider a full stop (`.`) to be a "word separator". There have been a few requests on [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) to change (upgrade?) this behavior; here are some that I could find:

- [What about an upgrade to the word delimiter list for a more accurate search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100656) — feature request from 10.5 years ago
- [Search word division is unintuitive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320489) — bug report from 3 years ago

---

In order to find the post you were looking for, you need to use wildcards `*` in your search string. For instance, searching for `cstheory*`, I do see the post you were looking for in the [search results](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=cstheory*).